# C++ EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 access=0x0)

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm writing a class for a connect 4 game, I am running into problems when I go to draw the board, the error, EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 access=0x0), keeps coming up when I try to reference my game_board member variable.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

```
#include "board.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Board::Board()
{
char** game_board=new char*[SIZEX];
for(int i=0; i<SIZEX; i++)
    game_board[i]=new char[SIZEY];


for (int i=0;i<SIZEX;i++)
 {
    for (int j=0;j<SIZEY;j++)
    {
        game_board[i][j]=' ';
    }
 }
};
void Board::draw()
{
    for (int j=0; j<SIZEY;++j )
    {
       cout<<"|---+---+---+---+---+---+---|\n";
        for (int i=0; i<SIZEX;++i)
        {
            cout<<"| "<<game_board[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"|\n";
   }
    cout<<"|---+---+---+---+---+---+---|\n";
};
Board::~Board()
{
    for(int i=0; i<SIZEX; i++)
        delete [] game_board[i];

    delete []game_board;

};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Board::Board()
{
    char** game_board=new char*[SIZEX];
    ^^^^^^
```

Here you are declaring a new `char** game_board` and allocating for it while your class's `game_board` is still unallocated.

I think your intention was to use the class member `Board::game_board`. In that case you should not declare it but just use it as it is (*it is already declared* ).

```
Board::Board()
{
   game_board=new char*[SIZEX];  // Or this->game_board=new char*[SIZEX]
```